# Mysql join tables but only results with a specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, join

three tables:
Customers (id_cus, cli_name, ...)
Products (id_pro, pro_name, ...)
Orders (id_cus, id_pro)

Table Orders is relation between Customers and Products.

Question is: **How to get Customers (id_cus) who choose only specific product.**

Example: *Product A* (id_pro= 100) and want all Clients customers who **only bought** this *Product A*, **not Product A and Product B**. Only Product A (id_pro = 100).

```
SELECT `id_cus` from `Orders` where `id_pro=100;
```

This give me all Customers who have ever bought Product A (and maybe Product B, C too).

Sorry, no idea.

Comment: Maybe this can help you [http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Simply:

```
SELECT o.id_cus
FROM orders o
WHERE o.id_pro = 100
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from orders o2 where o2.id_cus = o.id_cus AND o2.id_pro != 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation for this:

```
select o.id_cus
from orders o
group by o.id_cus
having min(o.id_pro) = max(o.id_pro) and min(o.id_pro) = 100;
```